# Encrypting Nexus 7 vs. screen lock

Tags: lock-screens, security, encryption

I read in this [article](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2145380/why-and-how-to-encrypt-your-android-device.html) that a non-encrypted tablet with only screen-lock on can have data read through USB.

Is this really true for example for a Nexus 7 tablet? I mean - if I lock the screen you can't get anywhere, even if you restart the device. Attempts to root it, or to hack it somehow when the bootloader is locked forces a data wipe and a factory reset. So is it really possible to get to the data in a screen-locked Nexus 7 which has no SD card?

The only way I can think about is that someone would somehow open the device and take the internal memory out and connected it somehow to a device which could read it. I presume that would be pretty expensive. If this really is the only way how to get to the data, it might be interesting to know, how much it may cost to do such a thing. If it is really costly, than it should be okay to just use screenlock.

Comment: What is your question, I'm sorry but I don't understand, is it: 'can you access encrypted data on an android phone?', is it 'can you access data on a non-encrypted android phone with screen lock?', or both, or another question entirely?

Comment: Can you access data on an encrypted android phone? No, you can't - not my question. Can you access data on a non-encrypted !Nexus 7! with screen lock? - yes, that is my question.

Comment: What is the difference between any Android device and Nexus 7?

Comment: Thanks, I believe you can, it depends, did you have usb debugging or root?

Comment: Actually, it's entirely possible to get root access without wiping data, if ADB is on. Privilege escalation exploits can do that.

Comment: - When you have a turned off device -> I was trying to turn on ADB, but when Nexus is turned off and you turn it on and go to bootloader or recovery mode, you cannot access adb, or you have only limited list of commands available.
- If you turn it on and you have a screen lock, it shouldn't let you read data until you unlock the device.
- Nexus 7 is built in a way, that they wanted to secure data entirely, in case of the tablet being stolen, so they disabled the ability to unlock the device to gain root privelege without first wiping the device completely.

Comment: If ADB is enabled and connected, it will completely ignore the screen lock state. Then, using the shell, it's possible to use unauthorized privilege escalation to gain root.

Comment: Yes, but that would be thus a human error - leaving the backdoor open, by having ADB enabled, when looking for security. So if we have a ADB disabled is encryption unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, as screen lock secures your data as long as the data chip stays in the phone(as long as debugging is disabled [or enabled with no trusted credentials] and the phone isn't rooted), whereas encrypting it secures it no matter what.

Old answer:
It is possible to access some data via usb, however other data isn't accessible, plug your tablet into the computer and wee what comes up under internal storage, that is accessible (EDIT: none of it if the screen is locked). Of course given enough time a hacker in possession of your tablet could access all the data (as long as it isn't encrypted) (EDIT: for example as you suggested by removing the internal storage and reading it with a different device).
If your tablet is encrypted none of the data can be accessed without your passcode (if the tablet is switched off).
If usb debugging is enabled or you are rooted it is even easier to access the data.

Comment: Well, not quite. I tried it out just now, just to be sure I'm not saying something that is not true. If you turn on a screenlocked device, after boot it stays screen locked. If you plug it in via USB, you cannot access ANY data. Yes, the device comes up, but it is entirely empty. After you unlock your screen, the internal storage is shown. Not otherwise. So your data are still behind the screenlock. Given enough time for a hacker is not enough for an answer - it may or may not be true. 

Leaving USB Debugging enabled is a security hole a user is responsible for and can be avoided.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the screen lock usb debugging disabled thing, however I'm unsure what security it gives to the bootloader

Comment: Bootloader itself is secured in a way, that if you have an unrooted device, which was not yet unlocked, you can do nothing but unlock if you wanna do anything else. And unlocking wipes all data.

Comment: Have updated my answer (which is basically your own answer)

Comment: If the data chip leaves the phone, it would only be readable with some special equipment, that could read the memory byte by byte. Is this an expensive thing to do?

Comment: I don't know, I expect the set up costs are relatively high, but the per read costs are extremely low, but not out of range if a government agency or corporate entity wanted you data, but probably out of range of most common criminals